# Как добавить дату и время в таблицу mysql

Tags: mysql, qt

Написал вот такой код:

```
QString datetimeMysql = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
qDebug() << datetimeMysql;
if(mysql_query(&mysql, "INSERT INTO TableEventBalancer VALUES ('1','datetimeMysql', 'Подача основного питания');"))
{
    qDebug() << mysql_error(&mysql);
}
```

В столбце `datetimeMysql` нуль.

Как добавить время `datetimeMysql` в столбец таблицы?

Comment: Так вы строку 'datetimeMysql' пытаетесь добавить, а не значение. Кавычки уберите.

Comment: Тогда получаю сообщение '"2020-05-09 19:22:39" 
Unknown column 'datetimeMysql' in 'field list''

Comment: Вам надо внутрь этой строки запроса вставить значение переменной.

Comment: @nightflash можно пример ?

Comment: "INSERT INTO TableEventBalancer VALUES ('1', " + datetimeMysql + ", 'Подача основного питания');" - конкатенация строк. К сожалению не подскажу, как это правильно в C# будет.

Comment: " + datetimeMysql + " тоже не катит error: cannot convert ‘const QString’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int mysql_query(MYSQL*, const char*)’
              if(mysql_query(&mysql, "INSERT INTO TableEventBalancer VALUES ('1', "+ datetimeMysql +", 'Подача основного питания');"))
Использую с++

Comment: Ну так вы сконвертируйте.

Comment: Что значит сконвертируйте ? Можно рабочий пример?

Answer (score 1):

не надо генерить currentDateTime() в коде. генерите его прямо в запросе:

```
INSERT INTO TableEventBalancer VALUES ('1',NOW(), 'Подача основного питания');

INSERT INTO TableEventBalancer VALUES ('1',CURDATE(), 'Подача основного питания');
```